# when reindex of sunspot. error: 503 Service Unavailable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

```
bundle exec rake sunspot:solr:reindex
Skipping progress bar: for progress reporting, add gem 'progress_bar' to your Gemfile
Error - RSolr::Error::Http - 503 Service Unavailable - retrying...
Error - RSolr::Error::Http - 503 Service Unavailable - ignoring...
Error - RSolr::Error::Http - 503 Service Unavailable - retrying...
Error - RSolr::Error::Http - 503 Service Unavailable - ignoring...
Error - RSolr::Error::Http - 503 Service Unavailable - retrying...
Error - RSolr::Error::Http - 503 Service Unavailable - ignoring...
Error - RSolr::Error::Http - 503 Service Unavailable - retrying...
Error - RSolr::Error::Http - 503 Service Unavailable - ignoring...
```

my rails version is 4.0.2

gem list | grep sunspot

sunspot (2.1.0)

sunspot_rails (2.1.0)

sunspot_solr (2.1.0)

Comment: I finally choose rails 4.0.0 with sunspot 2.0.0.maybe the newest version is not stable -_-!

Comment: I too was having this same issue and I'm on rails 3.2.13. I too downgraded both the sunspot_rails and sunspot_solr gems from 2.1.0 to 2.0.0 and it resolved it. One small catch was that after I updated the gemfile to lock in the 2.0.0 versions, I kept trying to run bundle update on either gem and it wouldn't work. I had to bundle update them both simultaneously: "bundle update sunspot_solr sunspot_rails"